# stopping sounds in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (guna2CheckBox2.Checked && guna2CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show("Please Choose One Box only");

        }
        else
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            ofd.ShowDialog();

            SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
            player.Play();
        }
    }

    private void guna2Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Hello  am making something to let user enter his wav file to played, and another button to let him stop the sound, but can not use player enter `enter code here code here player Stop
as it is out of context, any idea how to make the guna2Button stop the played sound in the else

Answer (score 1):

You should make the SoundPlayer a field (define it at class-level). This makes it accessible to all methods in your class.

```
private SoundPlayer player;

private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (guna2CheckBox2.Checked && guna2CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Choose One Box only");
    }
    else
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        ofd.ShowDialog();

        player = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
        player.Play();
    }
}

private void guna2Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the player is null (not defined yet), otherwise this could cause a NullReferenceException
    if (player != null) {
        player.Stop();
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to [learn about variable scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/), as this is a very important aspect of C# (and pretty much every other programming language).